# Is the principal object in Java EE security made for each request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

When a user tries to access a restricted resource on the webserver he/she is prompted with for example a login form. If he/she is authenticated is this information saved inside the Principal object in the session? I don't know if this is correct since you ask the request object of getting the principal object. Or is this retrieved done on each time the user makes a request. Can somebody help me understand this process?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the [servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) doesn't mention/mandate the mechanism of creation, storage or retrieval of the Principal object.

In other words, the decision of how to manage the Principal object would be left to the container providers

Comment: What do you think is done? On Glassfish for instance? Is it saved in the session?

Comment: If I cared about how Glassfish implemented it, I'd head over to https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/trunk right now.